# Why does the server process twice for show action in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server

```
Started GET "/microposts/29" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-27 22:08:41 +0800
Processing by MicropostsController#show as HTML
```

one time...

```
Started GET "/microposts/29" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-27 22:08:41 +0800
Processing by MicropostsController#show as */*
```

second time.

I have created micropost model with rails g scaffold, the server is in default setting, the index, create, and edit actions are all being processed one time.

I don't know why the show action got processed twice by the server? Can anyone help me with this? (ruby 2.3.3, rails 5.0.1)

Comment: Perhaps something to do with your routes? Do you mind posting your `routes.rb`?

Comment: I do not have a special setup for routes.rb neither.

Comment: resources :microposts

Comment: Did you fix your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some browsers (`Safari`) send Accept `*/*` which is not mapped to html format, and for some reason (alphabetic order?) maps to js format. Then protect_from_forgery kicks in and since this request doesn't have X-Requested-With (why should it? it's an ordinary get) browser comes back with a 422 response.

Technically this is not an issue with Rails but with the browser,

You can get rid of this by modifying `respond_to do |format|... end` block  (i think in create and update action from which its been redirected to show action.) comment line for `format.js` or `format.json`

Or,In controller:

```
before_action do
  if request.format == Mime::ALL
    request.format = request.xhr? ? :js : :html
  end
end
```

Comment: You are right! It is a browser issue. It occurs in Chrome and Chromium, but not in Firefox and Opera under ubuntu 16.04. I don't know about Safari.

Comment: I have tried both of your fixes, even combination of them. But they did not work. However, I still will give you credit for this. Thanks a lot! Gabbar.

Comment: Unfortunately, both Chrome and Safari browsers are so popular.

Comment: Commented out #protect_from_forgery with: :exception in application_controller.rb, did not fix the issue neither.